# No funciona mi autocompletar al presionar el tabulador

Tags: java, netbeans, tab

tengo un problema con la tecla sout+TAB al momento de autocompletar me borra el sout y no hace ninguna acción. Igual no me autocompleta algunas otros comandos.
He tratado de arreglarlo pero no he encontrado ninguna respuesta de utilidad, me sería de gran ayuda si alguien me pudiera explicar como solucionarlo.

sout
y luego +TAB y nada me lo borra

Comment: yo le cambié la opción de Tab por Space apliqué y luego le volví a cambiar pr Tab y funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

en el Netbeans ve a Tools>Options>Editor>Code Templates; en Languaje selecciona java y fíjate que en la columna abbreviation está agregado sout.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

OJO: Las abreviaciones tienen que estar dentro de un método para que al teclear TAB se autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó igual y lo pude solucionar. Lo que hice fué desinstalar tanto netbeans como la jdk que había instalado (Desde desinstalar aplicaciones de windows), luego eliminé los archivos de la caché de netbeans, estos están ubicados en:
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\xx.x) y  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\xx.x

En ambos casos borré la carpeta de NetBeans completa.

Luego descargué la jdk directamente de oracle, en mi caso descargué la jdk 19, la instalé y luego volví a instalar Netbeans nuevamente.
Nota: Recuerda verificar en las variables de entorno las variables Path y JAVA_HOME que estén bien configuradas.